# Facing problems in Fade Animation in android

Tags: android, android-animation, alpha-transparency

I am doing a simple alpha animation example where on click of a button the image appears as a fade  and the problem is that when i am running this and on clicking the button the app stops.
can anybody tell me what am i doing wrong?
here are my codes:-

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
private ImageView imageView;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
imageView=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image_view);
}
public void onAlphaButtonClick(){
Animation
 animation=AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext()
,R.anim.alpha);
}
```

res/anim/alpha.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<alpha xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
android:duration="5000"
android:fromAlpha="0.25"
android:toAlpha="1.0"
</alpha>
```

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:orientation="vertical"
>

<Button
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Alpha"
android:id="@+id/button"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<ImageView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/image_view"
android:src="@drawable/image"
android:layout_marginBottom="155dp"
android:layout_above="@+id/button"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Can you post the stacktrace of the crash?

Answer (score 0):

```
<Button
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Alpha"
android:id="@+id/button"

<!-- You need to add this line -->
android:onClick="onAlphaButtonClick"

android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

Comment: i added the onClick method but still it is not working